# Mockito when thenthrow not triggered by sonarQub coverage

Tags: java, mockito, sonarqube

my sonarQube coverage tests detect that the catch block of this code is never reached during tests

Code :

```
try{
  return FileUtils.convertFileToByte(project.getFolder()+".zip");
}catch(IOException ioe){
  throw new GeneratorException("Error when creating ",ioe);
}
```

my static function convertFileToByte() can throw a IOException.

Associated test:

```
try (MockedStatic<FileUtils> fileUtils = Mockito.mockStatic(FileUtils.class)) {
  fileUtils.when(() -> FileUtils.convertFileToByte(anyString())).thenThrow(IOException.class);
}
assertThatThrownBy(() -> repository.download(project)).isExactlyInstanceOf(GeneratorException.class);
```

I think the problems come from the fact that the "thenThrow" function is done after the execution and so consequently the catch block is never reached. I tried to separate the call return from assignation but it doesnt trigger the catch function in tests ever and add a code smell according to sonar.

Any idea, suggestions to make this test working ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try running your unit test without mock FileUtils?

Comment: Yes, makes much more error. Actually here i got this error : java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expecting code to raise a throwable. Which is really strange since the function is throwing an error

Answer (score 1):

So i found the solution and that wasn't specifically on this part of code. Thanks Juan for posting a comment. The fact was that i had a previous function in code generating the exact same Exception and when the error occured, it was during the first one and it never went through the second catch block.